# Mach-Zehnder probabilities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, probability, interferometry

Where can I find the computations of probabilities for [Mach-Zehnder experiments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%E2%80%93Zehnder_interferometer), say at the undergraduate level? For example I'm thinking of the type of experiments described at the beginning of David Albert's book?

Answer (score 1):

Robert Griffiths is quite fond of Mach-Zehnder experiments as useful windows into interpreting quantum foundations, and he presents calculations for some toy models of M-Z interferometers in Chapter 13 of his book, [Consistent Quantum Theory](http://quantum.phys.cmu.edu/CQT/).

As a caution, most of this book is written to parallel the consistent quantum histories formulation of quantum mechanics. The part of MZ interferometers should be intuitive to anyone who knows basic quantum mechanics, but there are some unusual tensor product notations and terminology about families of quantum histories which are unfamiliar to most readers. (This can be resolved by reading the introductory chapters; the entire book is provided online by the author.) The book is intended for the undergraduate level.